# Problem in understanding the reason behind the continuity of the irrational points in Thomae's Function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, proof-explanation

We consider $h:A\to\Bbb R$ where $A=(0,\infty).$

In Thomae's  Function we consider:

$$
\begin{align}
h(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}\\
\frac{1}{n} & \text{if $x = \frac{m}{n}$ where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

It is also to be noted that $x\in A.$

I was studying a proof about the fact that $h$ is continuous at the irrational points in $A$ from the book, "Real Analysis " by Robert G Bartle and Donald R Sherbert.

The proof went on as :

> If $b$ is an irrational number and $\epsilon > 0,$ then (by the Archimedean Property) there is a natural number $n_0$ such that $1/n_0 < \epsilon.$ There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$ (Why?) Hence
> $\delta > 0$ can be chosen so small that the neighborhood $(b-\delta, b+\delta)$ contains no rational
> numbers with denominator less than $n_0.$ It then follows that for $|x-b| < \delta; x \in A,$ we have $|h(x)-h(b)|=|h(x)|\leq 1/n_0\lt \epsilon.$ Thus $h$ is continuous at the irrational number $b.$

---

However, I have $3$ doubts regarding the proof.

**Doubt 1:** When they say,

> There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$

, how does they know that indeed there's a rational number(expressed in canonical form) whose denominator is less than $n_0$ is present in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$ I mean, it might so happen, that no  rationals (expressed in the canonical form) in the interval $(b-1,b+1)$ are there, whose denominator is less than $n_0.$ All rationals in the canonical form, with denomiantor $m$ where $m\lt n_0$ maybe outside the interval $(b-1,b+1).$

*My thoughts:* I think the proof is not saying that there exists at least one rational number in canonical form whose denominator is less than $n_0,$ but they are saying instead, that even if there is some rationals whose denominator is less than $n_0$ in canonical form, then the number of such rationals are finite.

But I don't know whether this is the thing intended ? **I need some confirmation.**

**Doubt 2:** Secondly, again, in that same statement i.e

> There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$

it is asserted that, that if such rational numbers exist they must be finite.

*My thoughts:* We know that there are, finite number of natural numbers less than $n_0$ i.e $n_0-1$ natural numbers are there. Similarly,  there exist a finite number of natural numbers in the interval $(b-1,b+1)$ say, $z$. Thus, the total number of rationals with dwnominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1)$ is **atmost** $z(n_0-1),$ which is finite. Hence, they made such a statement.

Am I correct in my thoughts/reasonings above ?

**Doubt 3:** How are the saying, $|h(x)-h(b)|=|h(x)|\leq 1/n_0\lt \epsilon,$ in their proof? I precisely don't get how did they write, $|h(x)|\leq 1/n_0$?

Comment: Zero would be a finite number.

Comment: You have mentioned "$h$ is continuous at the rational points in $A$". This appears to be a typo and you wanted to mean to "irrational points in $A$".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for pointing it out! I have fixed it. But I need an answer :?)

Comment: Well we have $n_0\geq 1$ and one can notice that $(b-1,b+1)$ contains an integer and that is a rational with denominator $1$ and hence there is a rational number in $(b-1,b+1)$ with denominator less than or equal to $n_0$.

Comment: Consider proving this: let $A_m$ be the set of rationals with denominator $m$ in lowest form. And let $I$ be a bounded interval. Then $A_m\cap I$ is a finite set (which can be empty as well). You can start by set $B_m=\{n/m\mid n\in\mathbb{Z} \} $ and then $A_m\subseteq B_m$ and prove $B_m\cap I$ to be finite

Comment: @ParamanandSingh With respect to this comment https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760685/problem-in-understanding-the-reason-behind-the-continuity-of-the-irrational-poin#comment10107239_4760685 : I think you meant 1 and yes, that answers my doubt 1.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you please be a little more explicit ? As I have posted my thoughts Doubt 1 and 2. I need a confirmation whether those are valid reasoning or not? Doubt 3 is what's bothering me.

Comment: Doubt 3: If $x$ is irrational $h(x) =0<1/n_0$ and if $x$ is rational then it has a denominator $n>n_0 $ and hence $h(x) =1/n<1/n_0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you please validate whether my answer to the OP: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4760714/1180560 is valid or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof given was :

> If $b$ is an irrational number and $\epsilon > 0,$ then (by the Archimedean Property) there is a natural number $n_0$ such that $1/n_0 < \epsilon.$ There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$ (Why?) Hence
> $\delta > 0$ can be chosen so small that the neighborhood $(b-\delta, b+\delta)$ contains no rational
> numbers with denominator less than $n_0.$ It then follows that for $|x-b| < \delta; x \in A,$ we have $|h(x)-h(b)|=|h(x)|\leq 1/n_0\lt \epsilon.$ Thus $h$ is continuous at the irrational number $b.$

---

The $3$ doubts regarding the proof were given in OP.

**Doubt 1:** When they say,

> There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$

, how does they know that indeed there's a rational number(expressed in canonical form) whose denominator is less than $n_0$ is present in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$ I mean, it might so happen, that no  rationals (expressed in the canonical form) in the interval $(b-1,b+1)$ are there, whose denominator is less than $n_0.$ All rationals in the canonical form, with denomiantor $m$ where $m\lt n_0$ maybe outside the interval $(b-1,b+1).$

**Answer:** They are not guaranteeing the existence of any such one rational number ( in canonical form whose denominator is less than $n_0,$) but the thing that is wanted to imply is that  if there is some rationals whose denominator is less than $n_0$ in canonical form, then the number of such rationals is finite. We note that, $0$ is a finite number as well.

**So, your Thoughts/Reasonings are correct in this case, as you mentioned in your OP.**

**Doubt 2:** Secondly, again, in that same statement i.e

> There are only a finite number of rationals with denominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1).$

it is asserted that, that if such rational numbers exist they must be finite.

> *My thoughts:* We know that there are, finite number of natural numbers less than $n_0$ i.e $n_0-1$ natural numbers are there. Similarly,  there exist a finite number of natural numbers in the interval $(b-1,b+1)$ say, $z$. Thus, the total number of rationals with dwnominator less than $n_0$ in the interval $(b-1,b+1)$ is **at most** $z(n_0-1),$ which is finite. Hence, they made such a statement.

Your thoughts/reasonings  are incorrect. This is because, the formula above simply does not work.

Instead, we can conclude it as:

If we assume, $k$ to be the number $1/n$ strips that can be made to cover $[a,b]$ then, $k/n=b-a$ and hence, $k=n(b-a)$. So, there are at most $n(b-a)$ rational numbers with denominator $n$ is $[a,b].$
But, the boundaries of the strips corresponds to each such rational and since the number of boundaries is equal to $n(b-a)+1$ so, the number of such rationals is atmost $n(b-a)+1,$ i.e finite.

---

So, to sum up,  **your thoughts regarding Doubt 1 is correct and accurate. But the formula in Doubt 2 gives a wrong result and hence, the formula needed to be modified.**

**Doubt 3:** How are the saying, $|h(x)-h(b)|=|h(x)|\leq 1/n_0\lt \epsilon,$ in their proof? I precisely don't get how did they write, $|h(x)|\leq 1/n_0$ ?

**Answer:** We can thus, find a small $\delta\gt 0$ such that the $\delta-$ neighborhood of $b$ contains no such rationals whose denominator is less than $n_0$ in canonical form. Thus, in $V_{\delta}(b)$ and $\forall x\in V_{\delta}(b)$ we have $h(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $x=\frac mn$ where $m,n\in\Bbb N$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $h(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational. So, if $h(x)=0$ then $h(x)\leq \frac{1}{n_0}$ and if $x=\frac mn,$ then, we have, $n\geq n_0$ and this implies, $h(x)=\frac 1n\leq \frac1{n_0}.$ So, $h(x)\leq \frac{1}{n_0}$  $\forall x\in V_{\delta}(b).$

Comment: The calculation (in doubt 2) about the maximum count $z(n_0-1)$ appears to be wrong. Essentially you evaluate the number of rationals with denominator $1$ and let their count be $n_1$. Similarly count of rationals with denominator $2$ be $n_2$ and so on. The total count of desired rationals is $n_1+n_2+n_{n_0-1}$. The point however is not to get the counts in explicit form via formula but just to prove that each of the counts $n_i$ is finite.

Comment: Other doubts have been resolved in your answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh But why is my count incorrect?

Comment: OK try calculating the number of rationals with denominator at most $4$ ($n_0=5$) in $(1,3)$. Your estimate is $z(n_0-1)=4$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, but what if I count the end points of $(1,3)$ then the estimate is, $12$ ? This is the max number of rationals in (1,3) satisfying the given criteria

Comment: Try the same example with $n_0=6,z=3$ then your estimate is $15$ but there are $19$ rationals in $(1,3)$ with denominator less than $6$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, then how to prove it? Please help me!

Comment: Use the sets $B_m=\{n/m\mid n\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ where $m$ is a positive integer. Can you notice that $B_m$ is an infinite set and more importantly any infinite subset of $B_m$ is unbounded? This implies that its intersection with any bounded set (in particular a bounded interval) is finite.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The part where you wrote, "This implies that its intersection with any bounded set (in particular a bounded interval) is finite." seems ambiguous to me, for "*its intersection with any bounded set (in particular a bounded interval) is finite*" is vacuously  true and this need not be implied  by something, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasFinley: For every $n\in \mathbb N$ less than $n_0$, how many possible numerators t for t/n, can you have in your case? You need to keep in mind that gcd(t,n)=1. Although, this calculation is not required here, you only need to know that there are only finitely many such rationals.

Comment: @Koro For each $n$ we can have $t$ as those numbers that are relatively prime to $n$ ?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: @Koro But how to prove the finiteness ?

Comment: @Koro You might edit my answer, to make that correct if you wish? But I wanna solve this bug...

Comment: In the interval $[a,b]$, there can be no more than $n(b-a)+1$ rational numbers with denominator $n$. Thus, there can be no more than $\frac{n^2+n}2(b-a)+n$ rational numbers with denominators no more than $n$. Here, we're overcounting, but that gives an upper bound.

Comment: You should observe that the set of rationals with a bounded denominator is a discrete set and there is a minimum distance between two elements of the set and that itself means that infinitely many members from this set will cover an unbounded length on the real line.

Comment: The distance between rational numbers with denominator $n$ is $\frac1n$.

Comment: Take any $\epsilon>0$. Look at the set $T=\{n\in \mathbb N: n\le \lfloor1/\epsilon\rfloor\}$. It is finite. For each $n\in T$, there are $\phi(n)$ natural numbers $\lt n$, which are coprime to $n$, i.e., there are at most $\sum_{n\in T} \phi(n)=K$ rational numbers $s/t$ for which $t\le 1/\epsilon$. Take $\delta<1$ and $\delta<1/2\min$ distance of the $K$ nos. from $b$. With this choice of $\delta$, clearly for every rational $p'/q'$ with $(p',q')=1$ in $(b-\delta, b+\delta),  1/q'<\epsilon,$ i.e., $|h(p'/q')-h(b)|=|h(p'/q')|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Here $\phi$ is the Euler's phi function and b has been assumed to be <1 which suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the question as well as the answer posted by the asker it is clear that the problem is in Doubt 2.

In particular one needs to prove that interval $(b-1,b+1)$ contains a finite number of rationals with denominators less than $n_0$.

To handle the situation where $n_0=1$ it is best to prove the following:

**Lemma**: Let $I$ be a bounded interval and let $m$ be a positive integer. Then $I$ contains a finite number of rationals with denominator less than or equal to $m$.

Let us consider the sets $$A_m=\{n/m\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}, \text{gcd} (n, m) =1\}, B_m=\{n/m\mid n\in\mathbb{Z} \} $$ Both these sets are infinite and $A_m\subseteq B_m$. Let us now observe that if $A$ is an infinite set with $A\subseteq B_m$ then $A$ is necessarily unbounded. This is because we then have infinitely many $n/m$ lying in $A$ and this means that we need integers $n$ with arbitrarily large absolute values and then set $A$ is unbounded.

Thus $A_m $ is unbounded but its intersection with a bounded interval $I$ is bounded and then $A_m\cap I\subseteq B_m$ is necessarily finite.

Further note that $A_{m_1}\cap A_{m_2}=\emptyset$ if $m_1\neq m_2$ and hence the set of all rationals lying in $I$ and having denominator less than or equal to $m$ is $$(A_1\cap I) \cup (A_2\cap I) \cup \dots\cup (A_m\cap I) $$ Since each of $A_i\cap I$ is finite their union above is also finite.